# xport list of duplicate images on digikam/findimagedupes/fsplint/geeqie

Tags: 12.04, scripts, photo-management, digikam

I have 60000 images. And when I ask any of the following tools to come up with similar photos, all of them pop out a big list of around 3000 names of images. digikam gives a cool UI which lets me see which images are similar and in which folders they are. But is there any way to create a csv out of this, where I can list duplicates and their locations for every image?

Can some script do this? Please let me know. Thanks! :)

The tools I used are these:

- digikam
- findimagedupes
- fsplint
- geeqie

Answer (score 1):

If there is the need to make interpolations and resizing there is room for errors, and similar (different resolution) images may be marked as duplicated. There is therefore the need for human verification.

Take a look at [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#doubles). The webpage looks ancient, but it's still good.

Answer (score 1):

It took a long time for me to find one that worked for me so I made a video on how to use this function.  Don't know about it creating list though

[image]

XnViewMP
http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/

[Link to youtube video showing how it works](http://youtu.be/gdHJHGWHROU)

Answer (score 0):

`findimagedupes -R ~/Pictures` generates a text file with all the matching image filenames. Installation: `sudo apt-get install findimagedupes`.